# How to return currentTab.url google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.tabs.query({   active: true,   currentWindow: true }, ([currentTab]) => {   console.log(currentTab.url); });
```

Code higher works but i want return current tab url.
If i use

```
return currentTab.url
```

It returns undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Callbacks in extensions API are invoked asynchronously, see the linked topic for explanations and solutions.